# Web scraping review section on agoda website with post request

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

need help with retrieving review section from agoda website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import json
from tqdm import tqdm


filename = "hotel.csv"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")

headers = "title, rating, review\n"
f.write(headers)

api_url = "https://www.agoda.com/api/cronos/property/review/ReviewComments"

headers = {
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
    }
# for loop for multiple page scrap
for x in tqdm(range(1,10)):
    post_data = {"hotelId":"2252947",
             "providerId":"332",
             "demographicId":"0",
             "page":str(x),
             "pageSize":"20",
             "sorting":"7",
             "providerIds":[332],
             "isReviewPage":"false",
             "isCrawlablePage":"true",
             "filters":{"language":[],"room":[]},
             "searchKeyword":"",
             "searchFilters":[]}

    html = requests.post(api_url, data=post_data)
    values = html.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(values, "html.parser")
    
    hotels = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "review-comment"})

    for hotel in hotels:
        try:
            rating = hotel.find("div", {"class":"Review-comment-leftScore"}).text

            title = hotel.find("p", {"class":"Review-comment-bodyTitle"}).text
            review = hotel.find("p", {"class":"Review-comment-bodyText"}).text

            f.write(title + ", "+ rating + ", " + review + "\n")
        except TypeError:
            continue
        

f.close()
```

post data i get from firefox network monitor when i change the page on the review section.
the hotel: [Hotel Page](https://www.agoda.com/hotel-uitm-shah-alam/hotel/shah-alam-my.html?cid=1844104)

tried the json method but i dont understand

Comment: @Wonka i have change the html.text() to html.text. and i have make the changes on the dict. the problem is that it does not output any data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your api endpoint or data is wrong. 'cause if you try just to print, you get <Response [415]>.
Should be 200.

> > > html.json()
> > > {'type': 'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13', 'title': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'status': 415, 'traceId': '00-68f23e7f0431e7bffae420112667ed1b-6306a38dd716894d-00'}